# MDX calculation of an Average Over Time with delta update on the fact table

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am having a problem creating this MDX calculation :

- Average Price of products over time knowing that my fact table gets price updates incrementally;

In order to calculate the average price of products at a certain point in time I have to lookup back to the latest prices of all the products (not all of the products necessarily get price updates at that point in time).

My fact table looks something like this :

**F_Products**

```
(Product_key,Date_Key,Price,flag_PriceChanged)
```

**Dim_Products**

```
(Product_key,ProductID,Price)
```

I had a success solving this using Chris Webb's [last ever non empty solution](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach) but it gets dramatically slower whenever I apply it on large set of products or over a large period of time.

The Calculations that I've used look something like this :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].DAYSTODATE AS
IIF([Measures].[Price]=NULL, NULL,  
COUNT(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER)-1);   

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].HADSALE AS   
IIF([Measures].[Price]=NULL, NULL, MEASURES.DAYSTODATE);      

SCOPE([Measures].MAXDATE, [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS);       
    THIS = MAX(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER, MEASURES.HADSALE);      
END SCOPE;      

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].LASTSALE AS  
IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].MAXDATE), NULL,   
([Measures].[Sales Price],  
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS.ITEM(MEASURES.MAXDATE)));      

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Average Price Incl. VAT]   
AS  
IIF( [Measures].HADSALE = NULL,NULL,  
    AVG([Dim Products].[Product ID].[Product ID],MEASURES.LASTSALE*1.25));
```

Any help Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to speed it up:

1. Put period attributes in Where clause: where ({NULL:[Date].[Date].[20160826]}).
2. Create a new fact table and update your last price every period (day,week,month, etc) you view your report.

Also you may play with PeriodsToDate function, but it returns **Set** which slows down your calculations anyway.

Comment: 1. I am afraid that filtering the results using : {NULL:[Date].[Date].[20160826]} would make the query even slower I am already using the date filter but on a smaller scope; still though the results are slow (14 days - one month period)    
2. I already have a dedicated fact table that holds the daily updates; the report has to be updated daily

Please feel free to throw any other suggestions.

Comment: 1.  Have you used LastNonEmpty Price within the filter? You have to add a measure from Price column with LastNonEmpty aggregation. Then rewrite MDX by removing LastNonEmpty logic. It's a way faster.